# How to add a column in default view in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

**Online Dynamics CRM:** When I open any section Lead/Opportunity/Account, I want **"Notes"** should be shown as a column with each record in respective section * (Lead/Opportunity/Account) * in default view because everytime opening each record to check associated Notes is time consuming.

Please guide.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've probably noticed you can't select the notes field as a column in any of the views.  One record potentially has many notes so which note would you expect to see on the grid?  They also typically contain long pieces of text which cannot be displayed in a meaningful way in the grid.  If you're using notes to store short pieces of text only, I'd reconsider the use of notes for this at all.

If you really need to do this you could use a plugin to copy the text of the last note added to a field on the entity then add this field to the Default View.